# While loop try/else/except

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to do in loop, go from else to try and when try didnt found go to except.

```py
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By. ID, 'pdp_size-reminder-dialog_title')
        print("Monitoring sizes")
    except:
        print("END.")
        break
    else:
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
        print("Reselecting size...")
        driver.find_element(By. ID, 'picker-trigger').click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='"+random.choice(sizes)+"']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

Comment: what is the problem ? The `break` should be at the end of "try" instead of "except"

Comment: @azro I need do this loop by then random size is avaible.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like that:

```
while True:
    res: Any | None = yields_elements()
    if res is None:
        break
    do_something()
    pause(2)
```

The yields_elements() might be critical for you, so it would need a try/finally block there instead.